# Prove that some group is infinite based on its presentation.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group with presentation $$G = \langle a, b, c\mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^3=(bc)^3=(ca)^3=1\rangle.$$

I want to show that this group is of infinite order.

I think since the element $abc$ is of infinite order, we can conclude that $G$ is infinite. I feel that for any $n \in\mathbb{N},$ we have that $(abc)^n = (abc)(abc) \cdots (abc)$ (with $n$ factors) cannot be reduced further, as we do not have any relations involving $a, b,$ and $c$ consecutively. But I also think that this reasoning is not that convincing, and hence, I am asking for help.

Comment: Unfortunately "I feel that ... " is not a mathematical proof!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to give a homomorphism from $G$ to a suitable group, such that the image of $abc$ has infinite order. For $G$ I cannot think of one without having to go into nasty matrix coefficients, but the following works:

Let $U=\langle b,abc\rangle$. This subgroup has index $[G:U]=3$. Then (by Reidemeister rewriting) $U$ has a presentation
$$
\langle b,d=abc\mid b^2,d^2bd^{-2}b\rangle
$$
in these two generators, which means that for the infinite cyclic group $C_\infty=\langle z\rangle$ the map $U\to C_\infty$, $b\mapsto 1$, $d\mapsto z$ is a homomorphism that proves that the order of $abc$ must be infinite.

**Addendum:** Actually, by inducing this representation up to $G$, we get a homomorphism into a matrix group, in which the image of $abc$ has infinite order:

Take the homomorphism $G\to\mbox{GL}_3(\mathbb{Q})$ given by
$$
a\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
0&1&0\\%
1&0&0\\%
0&0&1\\%
\end{array}\right)%
,\qquad
b\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
1&0&0\\%
0&0&2\\%
0&1/2&0\\%
\end{array}\right)%
,\qquad
c\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
0&0&1\\%
0&1&0\\%
1&0&0\\%
\end{array}\right).
$$

It is easy to verify that the images satisfy the relations, so it is a homomorphism. But it maps $abc$ to
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}%
2&0&0\\%
0&0&1\\%
0&1/2&0\\%
\end{array}\right)%
$$
which clearly has infinite order.

Comment: That's  clever! It might be helpful to mention that $|G:U|=3$. Then the calculation is an easy coset enumeration, which you can do by hand.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt . And of course I should have seen that I could just induce up to $G$ and then get a homomorphism defined on $G$ itself, removing the need for rewriting to verify the fact.

Comment: That last homomorphism is quite nice. but it is difficult to calculate

Answer (score 1):

This is the $(3,3,3)$ [triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group); consider one particular triangle in the tiling of the plane by equilateral triangles and define $a,b,c$ as reflections of the plane in its three sides. There are infinitely many triangles, so the group is of infinite order.

Comment: I think this answer world be brilliant if, instead of conjuring up the isomorphism from thin air/via a link, you explained in more detail why the given group $G$ maps onto the symmetries of the Euclidean plane tiled like this.

Comment: @user1729 It may be checked; I have no need to put this explicitly.

Comment: You don't need to do it explicitly, but you could at least explain *what* needs to be checked to verify that the group is infinite - what calculation the OP needs to do so that they can use your fact to solve their problem.